# SQLite get single datum (*single data)(update post)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm a beginner in Android. Please help me to solve this simple problem: retrieve a single datum from SQLite.

case 1 :

```
dbhelper.java
// Getting single part
    public lispar Look(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor kr = db.query(TABLE_PART, new String[]{ID,
                        KODE, NAMA}, ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if (kr != null)
            kr.moveToFirst();

        lispar contact = new lispar(Integer.parseInt(kr.getString(0)),
                kr.getString(1), kr.getString(2));
        // return contact
        kr.close();
        db.close();
        return contact;
    }
    
main.java
kodcari = (Button) findViewById(R.id.carikod);
        kodcari.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                ckodin = kodin.getText().toString(); //wrong string?
                parin.getText().toString();
                //what should i do?
            }
        });

        partnam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.namepart);
        dbHandle = new DbHandle(this);


    }
```

case 2 :

```
main.java ()

kodin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inkod);
        kodcari = (Button) findViewById(R.id.carikod);
        kodcari.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                String[] projection = {
                        FeedEntry._ID,
                        FeedEntry.KODE,
                        FeedEntry.NAMPART,
                        FeedEntry.BELANG
                };

                // Filter results WHERE "kode" = 'kode part'
                String selection = FeedEntry.KODE + " = ?";
                String[] selectionArgs = parin.getText().toString(), belangin.getText().toString();//{ "KODE_PART" }; //

                // How you want the results sorted in the resulting Cursor
                String sortOrder = FeedEntry.KODE + " DESC";

                Cursor kr = db.query(
                        FeedEntry.KODE,         // The table to query
                        projection,             // The columns to return
                        selection,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
                        selectionArgs,          // The values for the WHERE clause
                        null,                   // don't group the rows
                        null,                   // don't filter by row groups
                        sortOrder               // The sort order
                );
                if (kr != null)
                kr.moveToFirst();
                //String parin = kr.getString(
                //kr.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FeedEntry._ID)
                //);

            }
        });
```

main.xml

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Looking by Code"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:id="@+id/txkod"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="insert code"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/inkod"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txkod"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txkod"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txkod"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txkod"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txkod" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Look"
        android:id="@+id/carikod"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inkod"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/codepar"
        android:hint="code part"
        android:layout_below="@+id/namkod"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nampar"
        android:hint="name part"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nampar"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Inserting the data is successful, but reading a datum isn't.
(datum means data*)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1REtH.jpg)

Comment: It would appear that the method **`lispar`** would return a **contact** (your single datum I guess) object, but it's not called from what I can see. Perhaps calling **`lispar`** from where you have the `//What should I do?`, is what you want to do? I'd suggest NOT relying on `if (kr != null) kr.moveToFirst();` as if the cursor finds nothing the cursor will not be null. Perhaps use `if (kr.getCount()) == 1 kr.moveToFirst();`. What would happen if there were no rows in the cursor?

Comment: @MikeT : Thank you sir, and i'm sorry 4 this missunderstanding, about that code i try from many tutorial CRUD on internet, but still not working.
about `lispar` or `lispar.java` as `contact.java`.
i'm trying your tips by using `if (kr.getCount()) == 1 kr.moveToFirst();`, but still not working.
my expetation for this code like searching single data called by `kodin` editText. 
if `inputCode` fill && `btnCode` clicked`{dbHaldle = show AddSingleData
inputName(editText).getText ToString}` in same layout (main.xml && main.java)

Comment: oops in the post above I said lipsar instead of **Look**.

Comment: @MikeT thanks for you tips sir, in this case, maybe i must rebuild my code again from beginning, last code that i build take my time for 2 month but is still failed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all sure if the following will get you moving. But it appears that you are not getting the ID's of the views **kodin** and **parin**. So perhaps try the following:-

```
 kodin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inkod);
 parin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nampar);
```

More detailed code (*untested and written on the fly so may have errors*)

If you are using Android Studio or an IDE with debugging, then using that can be really helpful.

```
    kodcari = (Button) findViewById(R.id.carikod);
    // Adding the following lines may get the correct string
    kodin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inkod); //????
    parin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nampar); //????
    kodcari.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            ckodin = kodin.getText().toString(); //wrong string?
            parin.getText().toString();
            //what should i do? Perhaps the following :-
            lipsar myContact = Look(ckodin !!!!CONVERTED TO INT FROM STRING);
            // whatever else you need to do with the mycontact .....

        }
    });

    partnam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.namepart);
    dbHandle = new DbHandle(this);


}
```

Comment: thanks for you tips sir, maybe i must rebuild my code again from beginning, i'll try your code